Expectation and Variance of the sequence  in 4 tosses
I am trying to solve the following problem from Blitzstein's Introduction to Probability:

A coin with probability $p$ of Heads is flipped 4 times. Let $X$ be the
number of occurrences of $HH$ (for example, $THHT$ has 1 occurrence and
$HHHH$ has 3 occurrences). Find $E(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X)$.

To find the expectation, I note that $X=I_{1,2}+I_{2,3}+I_{3,4}$ where $I_{j,j+1}$ is the event that both tosses $j$ and $j+1$ are heads. Then since $E(I_{j,j+1}) = p^2$, we find $E(X)=3p^2$.
On the other hand, we can explicitly write down the probability mass function. Let $q=1-p$, then
\begin{align}
P(X=0) &= q^4 + 4q^3p + 3q^2p^2,\\
P(X=1) &= 3q^2p^2,\\
P(X=2) &= 4q^2p^2,\\
P(X=3) &= p^4.
\end{align}
The sum $\sum_{j=0}^3 P(X=j) =1$, as expected. However, the expectation is
\begin{equation}
E(X) = \sum_{j=0}^3 jP(X=j) = p^2 (-2 p^2 + 2 p + 3),
\end{equation}
which is inconsistent with the above answer.
I am confused what went wrong the above calculation. An analogue of the first method is used here, so I am reasonably sure this answer is correct. But I am confused why an application of the definition gives a different result.

Can you list out the sequences that give you $X=2$?

X=1: HTHT, THTH, HTTH
X=2: THHH, HHHT, [ HHTH, HTHH ]
Ahh so two of them are actually X=1.

I interpreted the problem as requiring the HH to be contiguous (i.e. none of those would count)

Oh sorry, I mistyped for X=1.
X=1: HHTT, TTHH, THHT
X=2: THHH, HHHT, [ HHTH, HTHH ]
But I think I miscounted my X=2.

I think that solves it then! Thanks.

Do your probabilties sum up to 1?

The probability mass function is incorrect. It should be
\begin{align}
P(X=0) &= q^4 + 4q^3p + 3q^2p^2,\\
P(X=1) &= 3q^2p^2 + 2q^2p^2,\\
P(X=2) &= 2q^2p^2,\\
P(X=3) &= p^4.
\end{align}
With this change, calculating the expected value from the definition should give the correct answer.
